# why is double aligned to 8 byte boundary instead of 4 byte

Tags: c, structure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why double in C is 8 bytes aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913120/why-double-in-c-is-8-bytes-aligned)

```
structure s{
    char a;
    double b;
    int c;
}d;
```

the sizeof d is 24.As it comes out to be double is aligned to 8 byte boundary.Can anybody explain why it is aligned to 8 byte boundary and not 4 byte boundary.I read somehwre that all elements are aligned to there size ? Why is it so

Answer (score 1):

Alignment is implementation-defined.

When there are alignment requirements for an object type, it is a value less or equal to the size of the object type. The alignment of the type is often the same as the size of the type.

When IEEE-754 is followed `double` usually corresponds to the `IEEE-754` `binary64` type which has a size of 8 bytes.