# Why structure padding is not happening properly?

Tags: c, padding

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct A
{
    char        c;
    double      e;
    int         s;
}A;

int main()
{
    printf("%u\n", sizeof(A));
    return 0;
}
```

It is giving output **16**. Shouldn't it be **24** if we consider structure internal padding and structure padding as a whole?

I am compiling the code on **Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit** with **GCC 4.8.2**.

Comment: Why should it be 24?

Comment: `1+3pad + 8 + 4 --> 16`  Looks good 4-byte alignment to me.

Comment: I think OP was expecting double to be aligned by 8 bytes.

Comment: @Mat, 1 byte for c + 7 byte padding + 8 byte for e + 4 byte for s + 4 byte for structure alignment if we declare array of structure and want to aligned internal members aligned in that case also. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Compiling with OS X 10.9.5 using gcc 4.2.1 I get 24.

Comment: Check [this general answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11110283/669567) , [this specific answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893802/why-is-a-double-member-in-struct-not-aligned-on-8-byte-boundary) and [a discussion to blow your mind](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10645)

Comment: Note that the padding *is* happening *properly*; it's just not happening as *you expected*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your calculations assume that `double` needs to be 8-byte aligned. That's not the case on all architectures.

On 32bit x86 Linux with GCC, `double` will be 4-byte aligned by default. You can change that with the `-malign-double` flag to make it 8-byte aligned.

So the layout assuming defaults on 32bit x86 Linux:

```
char       // 1 byte
           // 3 byte padding
double     // 8 bytes
int        // 4 bytes
```

So a total of 16 bytes, with 3 bytes of padding in the middle.

The Wikipedia article [Data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86) has size/alignment numbers for various types on 32bit x86 and 64bit x86_64 in a few compilers/environments.

Comment: I've never heard of byte aligning before. Why do C structs do this?

Comment: @Patrick, You can read on how cpu accesses memory. Google it.

Comment: Added a link to the Wikipedia article. Short version: CPUs need this. Unaligned accesses are either not possible or slow @PatrickRoberts

Comment: So GCC doesn't check what the native alignment should be?

Comment: @KyleStrand:  x86_64 supports 32bit-aligned accesses to 64bit floats, so that works (and probably saves some memory in some programs). There might be cases (CPU generations) when that's not optimal performance-wise (I don't know), and you have that switch if it matters for you.