# Different machine code for empty default constructor v. implicitly-defined one

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, x86-64, c++20

Given the following struct...

```
#include <type_traits>

struct C {
    long a[16]{};
    long b[16]{};

    C() = default;
};

// For godbolt
C construct() {
    static_assert(not std::is_trivial_v<C>);
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<C>);

    C c;
    return c;
}
```

...gcc (version 10.2 on x86-64 Linux) with enabled optimization (at all 3 levels) produces the following assembly<sup>[1]</sup> for `construct`:

```
construct():
        mov     r8, rdi
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     ecx, 32
        rep stosq
        mov     rax, r8
        ret
```

Once I provide empty default constructor...

```
#include <type_traits>

struct C {
    long a[16]{};
    long b[16]{};

    C() {}  // <-- The only change
};

// For godbolt
C construct() {
    static_assert(not std::is_trivial_v<C>);
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<C>);

    C c;
    return c;
}
```

...generated assembly changes to initializing every field individually instead of single memset in the original:

```
construct():
        mov     rdx, rdi
        mov     eax, 0
        mov     ecx, 16
        rep stosq
        lea     rdi, [rdx+128]
        mov     ecx, 16
        rep stosq
        mov     rax, rdx
        ret
```

Apparently, both structs are equivalent in terms of not being trivial, but being standard layout.
Is it just gcc missing an optimization opportunity, or is there more to it from the C++-the-language perspective?

---

The example is a stripped down version of production code where this did have material difference in performance.

---

[1] Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/8n1Mae

Comment: g++ is probably coded with an optimised behaviour when using the `= default`,  but doesn't check if a hand-rolled constructor can be similarly optimised. It's quite common for compilers to not consider every optimisation opportunity.   In this case, g++ developers probably didn't consider that a hand-rolled constructor with an empty body and not explicit initialisers was worth worrying about.  If you think it's important, make a suggestion (to the g++ team, not here). Or simply update your coding standards to prefer the `=default`.

Comment: At least, the question is a nice recommendation to prefer `= default` over `{ }` for default constructors. (Something, I ever somehow felt since I learnt the option `= default`.) ;-)

Comment: @Peter: Yeah, looks like the `= default` constructor is looking at the whole object as a single object as a candidate for memset init, while the `C(){}` explicit constructor is only looking at the individual members separately and fails to merge the memsets.  That's clearly a missed optimization which you can report to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/.  There are probably real-world cases with multiple zeroed members but still some init code to run.  It only really becomes most visible when GCC chooses to expand memset as `rep stos` or loops, instead of fully unrolled `vmovdqu` stores.

Comment: With `-march=skylake`, instead of rep stos we see two separate loops for the split version.  https://godbolt.org/z/Y1KeYW.  (Using scalar stores, which is a separate memset-expansion missed optimization.  GCC only uses wide SIMD stores when fully unrolling.  [Trying to understand clang/gcc \_\_builtin\_memset on constant size / aligned pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65534658).  GCC8 and earlier still used rep stos which has significant startup overhead but can be better than 16-byte stores.)  Anyway, certainly no advantage to 2 separate smaller memsets whatever strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree that this seems like a missed optimization opportunity, I noticed one difference from the language level perspective. The implicitly-defined constructor is `constexpr` while the empty default constructor in your example is not. From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-defined_default_constructor):

> That is, [the implicitly-defined constructor] calls the default constructors of the bases and of the non-static members of this class. If this satisfies the requirements of a constexpr constructor, the generated constructor is constexpr (since C++11).

So as the initialization of the arrays of `long` is `constexpr`, the implicitly-defined constructor is as well. However, the user-defined one is not, as it is not marked `constexpr`. We can also confirm this by trying to make the `construct` function of the example `constexpr`. For the implicitly-defined constructor this works without any problems, but for the empty user-defined version it fails to compile because

> <source>:3:8: note:   'C' is not an aggregate, does not have a trivial default constructor, and has no 'constexpr' constructor that is not a copy or move constructor

as we can see here: https://godbolt.org/z/MnsbzKv1v

So to fix this difference we can make the empty user-defined constructor `constexpr`:

```cpp
struct C {
    long a[16]{};
    long b[16]{};

    constexpr C() {}
};
```

Somewhat surprisingly, gcc now generates the optimized version, i.e. the exact same code as for the defaulted default constructor: https://godbolt.org/z/cchTnEhKW

I do not know why, but this difference in `constexpr`ness actually seems to help the compiler in this case. So while it seems like gcc should be able to generate the same code without specifying `constexpr`, I guess it is good to know that it can be beneficial.

---

As an additional test for this observation, we could try to make the implicitly-defined constructor non-`constexpr` and see if gcc fails to do the optimization. One simple way that I can think of to try to test this is to have `C` inherit from an empty class with a non-`constexpr` default constructor:

```cpp
struct D {
    D() {}
};

struct C : D {
    long a[16]{};
    long b[16]{};

    C() = default;
};
```

And indeed, this generates the assembly that initializes the fields individually again. Once we make `D()` `constexpr`, we get the optimized code back. See https://godbolt.org/z/esYhc1cfW.