# How to use AVX instructions to optimize ReLU written in C

Tags: c, vectorization, conditional-operator

I have the following simplified ReLU simulation code that I am trying to optimize. The code uses a ternary operation which is perhaps coming in the way of automatic vectorization by the compiler. How can I vectorize this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mkl.h>

void relu(double* &Amem, double* Z_curr, int bo)
{
    for (int i=0; i<bo; ++i) {
        Amem[i] = Z_curr[i] > 0 ? Z_curr[i] : Z_curr[i]*0.1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int batch_size = 16384;
    int output_dim = 21;
    // double* Amem = new double[batch_size*output_dim];
    // double* Z_curr = new double[batch_size*output_dim];
    double* Amem = (double *)mkl_malloc(batch_size*output_dim*sizeof( double ), 64 );
    double* Z_curr = (double *)mkl_malloc(batch_size*output_dim*sizeof( double ), 64 );
    memset(Amem, 0, sizeof(double)*batch_size*output_dim);
    for (i=0; i<batch_size*output_dim; ++i) {
        Z_curr[i] = -1+2*((double)rand())/RAND_MAX;
    }
    relu(Amem, Z_curr, batch_size*output_dim);
}
```

To compile it, if you have MKL then use the following, otherwise plain g++ -O3.

```
g++ -O3 ex.cxx -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5
```

So far, I have tried adding -march=skylake-avx512 as a compiler option, but it does not vectorize the loop as I found using option -fopt-info-vec-all for compilation:

```
ex.cxx:9:16: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
ex.cxx:9:16: missed: not vectorized: control flow in loop.
ex.cxx:6:6: note: vectorized 0 loops in function.
ex.cxx:9:16: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
ex.cxx:9:16: missed: not vectorized: control flow in loop.
```

and this is the time it takes currently at my end:

```
time ./a.out
real    0m0.034s
user    0m0.026s
sys     0m0.009s
```

Comment: In  what case is `Z_curr[i] ? Z_curr[i] : Z_curr[i]*0.1` different from `Z_curr[i]`?

Comment: Actually this should be ```Z_curr[i] > 0 ? Z_curr[i] : Z_curr[i]*0.1;``` I am correcting it.

Comment: It does do some vectorization if I do `Amem[i] = Z_curr[i] * (std::copysign(0.45, Z_curr[i]) + 0.55);`, which should be equivalent unless you depend on signed zero or NaN behavior.

Comment: @Ruslan Much simpler would be `max(Z_curr[i], 0.1*Z_curr[i])`  (should even work for infinity or NaN)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is usually no benefit to pass a pointer by reference (unless you want to modify the pointer itself). Furthermore, you can help your compiler using the (non-standard) `__restrict` keyword, telling it that no aliasing happens between input and output (of course, this will likely give wrong results, if e.g., `Amem == Z_curr+1` -- but `Amem == Z_curr` should (in this case) be fine).

```
void relu(double* __restrict Amem, double* Z_curr, int bo)
```

Using that alone, clang actually is capable of vectorizing your loop using `vcmpltpd` and masked moves (for some reasons, only using 256bit registers).

If you simplify your expression to `std::max(Z_curr[i], 0.1*Z_curr[i])` even gcc easily is capable of vectorizing it: https://godbolt.org/z/eTv4PnMWb

Generally, I would suggest compiling crucial routines of your code with different compilers and different compile options (sometimes trying `-ffast-math` can show you ways to simplify your expressions) and have a look at the generated code. For portability you could then re-translate the generated code into intrinsics (or leave it as is, if every compiler you care about gives good-enough results).

For completeness, here is a possible manually vectorized implementation using intrinsics:

```
void relu_avx512(double* __restrict Amem, double* Z_curr, int bo)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<=bo-8; i+=8)
    {
        __m512d z = _mm512_loadu_pd(Z_curr+i);
        __mmask8 positive = _mm512_cmplt_pd_mask (_mm512_setzero_pd(), z);
        __m512d res = _mm512_mask_mul_pd(z, positive, z, _mm512_set1_pd(0.9));
        _mm512_storeu_pd(Amem+i, res);
    }
    // remaining elements in scalar loop
    for (; i<bo; ++i) {
        Amem[i] = 0.0 < Z_curr[i] ? Z_curr[i] : Z_curr[i]*0.1;;
    }
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/s6br5KEEc (if you compile this with `-O2` or `-O3` on clang, it will heavily unroll the cleanup loop, even though it can't have more than 7 iterations. Theoretically, you could do the remaining elements with a masked or overlapping store (or maybe you have use-cases where the size is guaranteed to be a multiple of 8 and you can leave it away).

Comment: Got it. There is a backward pass that has an expression like ```dZcurr[i] = (Z_curr[i] > 0) ? dAcurr[i] : 0.1*dAcurr[i];``` In here i think we do have to deal with the ternary though? Also, thanks for the godbolt site that gives a far better picture of the results of the compilation.

Comment: For the backwards expression, you may need to use intrinsics, or switch to clang if that is possible for you.

Comment: You can force the use of 512-bit registers with `-mprefer-vector-width=512`.  This isn't the default because it sometimes actually hurts performance, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523349/avx-512-vs-avx2-performance-for-simple-array-processing-loops/52523647#52523647

Comment: @chtz: thank you for the code snippet with intrinsics. i also wanted to know your opinion about parallelizing the ```for (i=0; i<=bo-8; i+=8)``` among multiple threads. I tried adding #pragma omp for, but it increases the runtime many-folds.

Comment: @NateEldredge: thank you for the suggestion, it helps the performance in my case.

Comment: @Tania regarding multithreading better ask a new question (if you can't find an existing one). But your problem size is probably just too small.