# Why does the vhaddps instruction add in such an involved way?

Tags: assembly, x86, avx

The `vhaddps` instruction adds in a very peculiar way:

[image]

Source: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/haddps

What is the reason for this? What use cases is this instruction made for? It looks like the design has something specific in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 2 in-lane `haddps` instructions in the low and high 128-bit lanes.  **Most AVX instructions don't really widen the operation to 256-bit, they do 2 separate in-lane operations**.  This makes AVX hard to use, especially without AVX2 for lane-crossing shuffles with less than 128-bit granularity!

But it saves transistors vs. e.g. making `vpshufb` a single 32-byte shuffle instead of 2x 16-byte shuffles.  AVX2 doesn't even provide that: [Where is VPERMB in AVX2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980209/where-is-vpermb-in-avx2)  (Have to wait for AVX512VBMI).

(related: [best way to shuffle across AVX lanes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982211/best-way-to-shuffle-across-avx-lanes)  Also, AVX512 adds a lot of flexible lane-crossing shuffles, but the AXV512 versions of SSE/AVX instructions like `vhaddps zmm` are still in-lane.  See also [Do 128bit cross lane operations in AVX512 give better performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646238/do-128bit-cross-lane-operations-in-avx512-give-better-performance))

A chain of AVX2 `vpack*` typically needs a `vpermq` to do a lane-crossing fixup at the end, unless you're going to unpack in-lane again.  **So in most cases, 2x in-lane shuffles are worse than a full 256-bit wide operation, but that's not what we get from AVX.**  There's often still a speedup to be had from going to 256-bit vector up from 128 even if it requires extra shuffles to correct for in-lane behaviour, but that often means it's not a 2x speedup even if there are no memory bottlenecks.

`vpalignr` is probably the most egregious example of 2x 128-bit versions of the same shuffle being not a useful building block on its own; I can't remember if I've ever seen a use-case for taking 2 separate in-lane byte windows of data.  Oh, actually yes, if you feed it with `vperm2i128` [How to concatenate two vector efficiently using AVX2? (a lane-crossing version of VPALIGNR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45245732/how-to-concatenate-two-vector-efficiently-using-avx2-a-lane-crossing-version-o) but usually unaligned loads are better on CPUs that support AVX2.

---

## The use-cases for `(v)haddps` are very limited

Maybe Intel planned to maybe make `haddps` into a single-uop instruction at some point after introducing it with SSE3, but that never happened.

**The use-cases include transpose-and-add type things** where you'd need to shuffle both inputs for a vertical `addps` anyway.  e.g. [Most efficient way to get a __m256 of horizontal sums of 8 source __m256 vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195356/most-efficient-way-to-get-a-m256-of-horizontal-sums-of-8-source-m256-vectors) includes `vhaddps`.  (Plus  AVX1 `vperm2f128` to correct for the in-lane behaviour.)

Many people mistakenly think it's good for horizontal sums of a single vector, but both 128 and 256-bit `(v)haddps` decode to 2x shuffle uops to prepare input vectors for a vertical `(v)addps` uop.  For a horizontal sum you only need 1 shuffle uop per add.  ([Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86/35270026#35270026))

Narrowing to 128-bit first (with `vextractf128` / `vaddps`) is usually a better first step unless you want the result broadcast to every element, and you're not on an AMD CPU (where 256-bit vector operations decode to at least 2 uops, or more for lane-crossing shuffles).  `(v)haddps xmm` or integer `vphaddd` are useful for horizontal sums if you're optimizing for code-size not speed, e.g. [my x86 machine-code answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182460/calculate-the-mean-mean-of-two-numbers/182548#182548) on the code-golf question "Calculate the Mean mean of two numbers".

AVX non-destructive destination operands also remove some of the appeal of having a multi-uop instruction.  Without AVX, sometimes you can't avoid a `movaps` to copy a register before destroying it, so baking 2x shuffle + add into 1 instruction did actually save uops vs. having to do that manually with `movaps` + `shufps`.

Comment: I guess your speed of typewriting is much higher than mine.:)

Comment: @wim: I can type text pretty quickly, yeah :)  I learned good habits from the start; my dad had a typing-tutor game called Word Invaders on the Atari ST which I played some as a teen back in the 90s, so I've always touch-typed and known how you're *supposed* to type efficiently, which I mostly follow.  And I've had quite a few years of practice by now. :P

Comment: I started typewriting at a ZX Spectrum, that explains a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As with many 256-bit wide instructions the upper 128 bits 
of `vhaddps ymm ymm ymm` are just a copy paste of the 128-bit wide `vhaddps xmm xmm xmm`
instruction. The following example shows that it makes sense to 
define `vhaddps xmm xmm xmm` in such an involved way: Using this instruction twice
gives you the horizontal sum of 4 `xmm` registers.

```c
/* gcc -m64 -O3 hadd_ex.c -march=sandybridge           */
#include<immintrin.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    float tmp[4];
    __m128 a = _mm_set_ps(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
    __m128 b = _mm_set_ps(10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0);
    __m128 c = _mm_set_ps(100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0);
    __m128 d = _mm_set_ps(1000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0, 4000.0);
    __m128 sum1 = _mm_hadd_ps(a, b);
    __m128 sum2 = _mm_hadd_ps(c, d);
    __m128 sum = _mm_hadd_ps(sum1, sum2);
    _mm_storeu_ps(tmp,sum);
    printf("sum = %f  %f  %f  %f\n", tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sum = 10.000000  100.000000  1000.000000  10000.000000
```