# How to load two packed 64-bit quadwords into a 128-bit xmm register

Tags: assembly, x86, language-agnostic, sse2

I have two UInt64 (i.e. 64-bit quadword) integers.

- they are aligned to an 8-byte (`sizeof(UInt64)`) boundary *(i could also align them to 16-byte if that's useful for anything)*
- they are packed together so they are side-by-side in memory

How do i load them into an xmm register, e.g. `xmm0`:

[image]

---

I've found:

```
movq xmm0, v[0]
```

but that only moves **`v[0]`**, and sets the upper 64-bits in `xmm0` to zeros:

> xmm0 <kbd>`0000000000000000 24FC18D93B2C9D8F`</kbd>

### Bonus Questions

- How do i get them back out?
- What if they're not side-by-side in memory?
- What if they're 4-byte aligned?

## Edit

As W. Chang pointed out, the endiannessification is little, and i'm ok with it being other way around:

[image]

My conundrum is how to get them in, and get them out.

Comment: For future questions like this, refer to [this nice overview](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) over the available instructions.

Comment: Is there a guide that explains the guide? Without knowing what the reference is, all i see is, *"underscore five one two underscore four dee pee double u es es dee underscore pee eye thirty two"*. Whereas, i'm looking for i) how to put UInt64's into xmm ii) how to add two 64-bit integers in parallel, and how to get the answer back. Without a guide that decodes the guide, i'm staring at...god...there must be 900 operations in there. The three i want seem to be a secret.

Comment: Intrinsics are C-style functions that closely related to assembly. Each intrinsics function corresponds to one or a few assembly instructions. They are inlined (without function call overhead) and are as efficient as writing assembly, most of the time.

Comment: Is it necessary to load them in reverse (with the second element into the low half of the vector register) like this?

Comment: Note that Peter's answer below loads V[0] to the lower half of an XMM register. In your drawing V[0] is in the upper half. Intel/AMD CPUs are little-endian, meaning that the first byte is stored in the lowest 8-bit, and so on. So it is unusual to have V[0] in the upper half.

Comment: @W.Chang: oh good catch, I just read that they were contiguous, and didn't notice that they were in the wrong order.  So yeah, a memory-source `pshufd` would be one way to go, if they were 16-byte aligned.  (Or with AVX, you can do it without an alignment requirement with `vpshufd xmm0, [mem], something`)

Comment: @IanBoyd You can select instruction sets and categories on the left.  Then, you can use the search function to search for terms you find interesting.  Each entry has pseudo-code outlining what it does.  What you are most interested in is the instruction mnemonic given in the description; that's what the instruction is called when you program in assembler.

Comment: Why does this have the tag `language-angnostic` and also have the tag `assembly`?

Comment: @GuyCoder I didn't want anyone thinking i had access to any compiler intrinsics available to some particular (higher-level) languages. I also don't want to be pedantic and say that it's **machine code** rather than **assembly language** - nobody cares about that distinction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an unaligned 128-bit load, use:

- [**`movups xmm0, [v0]`**](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVUPS.html): *move unaligned single-precision floating point* for `float` or `double` data.  (`movupd` is 1 byte longer but never makes a performance difference.)
- [**`movdqu xmm0, [v0]`**](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVDQU:VMOVDQU8:VMOVDQU16:VMOVDQU32:VMOVDQU64.html): *move unaligned double quadword*

Even if the two quadwords are split across a cache-line boundary, that's normally the best choice for throughput.  (On AMD CPUs, there can be a penalty when the load doesn't fit within an aligned 32 byte block of a cache line, not just a 64-byte cache-line boundary.  But on Intel, any misalignment within a 64-byte cache line is free.)

If your loads are feeding integer-SIMD instructions, you probably want `movdqu`, even though `movups` is 1 byte shorter in machine code.  Some CPUs may care about "domain crossing" for different types of loads.  For stores it doesn't matter, many compilers always use `movups` even for integer data.

---

See also [How can I accurately benchmark unaligned access speed on x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128763/how-can-i-accurately-benchmark-unaligned-access-speed-on-x86-64) for more about the costs of unaligned loads.  (SIMD and otherwise).

If there weren't contiguous, your best bet is

- [**`movq xmm0, [v0]`**](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVQ.html): *move quadword*
- [**`movhps xmm0, [v1]`**](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVHPS.html): *move high packed single-precision floating point*.  (No integer equivalent, use this anyway.  Never use `movhpd`, it's longer for no benefit because no CPUs care about double vs. float shuffles.)

Or on an old x86, like Core2 and other old CPUs where `movups` was slow even when the 16 bytes all came from within the same cache line, you might use

- **`movq xmm0, [v0]`**: *move quadword*
- **`movhps xmm0, [v0+8]`**: *move high packed single-precision floating point*

`movhps` is slightly efficient than [SSE4.1 `pinsrq xmm0, [v1], 1`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PINSRB:PINSRD:PINSRQ.html) (2 uops, can't micro-fuse on Intel Sandybridge-family: 1 uop for loads ports, 1 for port 5).  `movhps` is 1 micro-fused uop, but still needing the same back-end ports: load + shuffle.

**See Agner Fog's x86 optimization guide; he has a chapter about SIMD with a big section on data movement. https://agner.org/optimize/**  And see other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

---

To get the data back out, `movups` can work as a store, and so can `movlps`/`movhps` to scatter the qword halves.  (But don't use `movlps` as a load- it merges creating a false dependency vs. `movq` or `movsd`.)

`movlps` is 1 byte shorter than `movq`, but both can store the low 64 bits of an xmm register to memory.  Compilers often ignore domain-crossing (vec-int vs. vec-fp) for stores, so you should too: generally use SSE1 `...ps` instructions when they're exactly equivalent for stores.  (Not for reg-reg moves; Nehalem can slow down on `movaps` between integer SIMD like `paddd`, or vice versa.)

In all cases AFAIK, no CPUs care about `float` vs. `double` for anything other than actual add / multiply instructions, there aren't CPUs with separate `float` and `double` bypass-forwarding domains.  The ISA design leaves that option open, but in practice there's never a penalty for saving a byte by using `movups` or `movaps` to copy around a vector of `double`.  Or using `movlps` instead of `movlpd`.  `double` shuffles are sometimes useful, because `unpcklpd` is like `punpcklqdq`  (interleave 64-bit elements) vs. `unpcklps` being like `punpckldq` (interleave 32-bit elements).

Comment: Perhaps also say something about integer vs. floating point domains with respect to which of `movups` and `movdqu` to select.