# Does modern x86-64 cpu still benefit from memory data alignment?

Tags: performance, memory, x86, x86-64, memory-alignment

As titled,

I've searched a lot of old articles on the Internet regarding memory data alignment, but I am not sure whether they are still useful nowadays. So, the question is regarding modern x86-64 CPUs, whether the memory data alignment is still beneficial for efficient data access? Or just an old convention adopted by all compilers for backward compatibility?

Answer (score 2):

Yes for arrays because it means you'll avoid cache-line and page splits.  See [How can I accurately benchmark unaligned access speed on x86_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128763/how-can-i-accurately-benchmark-unaligned-access-speed-on-x86-64/45129784#45129784) for details on various penalties and how to measure them.

This is especially significant for vectorization with AVX-512, where looping over a misaligned array with 512-bit vectors means every load is a cache-line split.  The penalty can be ~20%, vs. a few % with AVX 256-bit vectors on the same CPU even for data that's coming from L3 or DRAM, not L2 or L1d hits.

No for misalignment within a single cache line, for both integer and SIMD loads/stores on modern AMD and Intel microarchitectures.  (Except for legacy-SSE where only aligned loads can be folded into a memory source operand like `addps xmm0, [rdi]` instead of separate `movups`.  Unlike AVX where `vaddps xmm0, xmm0, [rdi]` doesn't require alignment.)

And yes potentially indirectly in terms of keeping all a struct's members in the same cache line, improving spatial locality.