# Performing unaligned access on x86-64 without crossing the boundary

Tags: c, assembly, memory, x86, x86-64

On x86-64, the processor can access 8-byte chunks of memory in one reading, and unaligned access requires a second reading, but ONLY if the variable "crosses" the 64-bit boundary. So if some variable (16 or 32 bits) is unaligned, but inside the 64-bit boundary, does it count as unaligned access?

For example, if I have a 16-bit variable *var* starting at address 0x1001, and I access it with `mov ax, [0x1001]` to obtain its 16-bits, I will be doing an unaligned access (since the address is not divisible by 2), even if the processor accesses 8 bytes at once (from 0x1000 to 0x1007) and therefore obtaining the 2 bytes of *var* in just one reading? I know that if it was in the address 0x1007 it would require 2 readings, but what if it was inside the first chunk?

I noticed that in ARM doing something like this doesn't end in any error. I know x86 deals with unaligned access, but I want to know whether this situation IS an unaligned access in reality (causing errors and/or multiple MORE cycles to complete).

Comment: Even a memory access that crosses a cache line usually only takes one extra cycle to complete.  It's not super expensive.

Comment: See also [How can I accurately benchmark unaligned access speed on x86_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45128763/555045)

Comment: "*does it count as unaligned access*" — the term [unaligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Definitions) has a generally accepted definition.  Asking about performance of unaligned accesses does not require defining/inventing new terminology such as, say, "unaligned in reality" vs. "unaligned theoretically".

Comment: Your first paragraph seems to be describing the atomicity guarantees from AMD (which are weaker than Intel) for cacheable load/store.  [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36685056), except tearing at that boundary isn't necessarily from multiple accesses, it can be from the interconnect.  On Zen 1 or 2, only crossing a 16-byte or 32-byte boundary matters, and on Zen 3 and 4 it's like Intel that only a 64-byte cache-line boundary matters.  https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2019/06/11/speed-limits.html#store-split-cache-lines

Comment: (Interestingly, the boundaries that matter for loads are wider than for stores on Zen: https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2019/06/11/speed-limits.html#load-split-cache-lines)

Comment: So really the question to ask for x86 performance isn't whether the access is aligned, it's what boundary you cross.

Comment: I think you guys missed the point from something simple and went to "cache" instead, but it's a good thing, because I didn't even consider it previously. If the article @ErikEidt referenced is correct, then it answers my question, it says: "[...] in a 32-bit architecture, the data may be aligned if the data is stored in four consecutive bytes and the first byte lies on a 4-byte boundary." The data in my question is stored in 0x1001 and 0x1002, but 0x1000 is aligned.

Comment: So, for the cache matter, @PeterCordes, do the example cross the boundary? Because if the boundary is 64 bytes this variable should be in the boundary, right?

Comment: Your example access is fully contained within an aligned 4-byte chunk, and thus doesn't span across any larger power-of-2 boundaries either, such as a 64-byte cache line.

Comment: @boltragons We could consider DRAM as well but I don't think that would yield anything interesting, would it? Basically the same thing happens, but after waiting for a cache line to be filled from DRAM. Maybe something interesting happens for uncached loads?